# SharedPreferences not working as expected, cannot read nor write preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

```
private void init() {

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // SET VALUE RECORD

    record = prefs.getInt("record", 0);

    prefs.edit().commit();
}

private void setRecord(int i ) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(i > prefs.getInt("record", 0))
        prefs.edit().putInt("record", i);

    prefs.edit().commit();
}

private int getRecord() {

    int rec;

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    rec = prefs.getInt("record", 0);

    prefs.edit().commit();

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, rec+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    return rec;
}
```

this code should set an int and retrieve it, but it doesn't seem to ever set it... can you see why is that?

Comment: if(i > prefs.getInt("record", 0))
       For this to work you must have put a record in before. Where do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it is best to call the interface `SharedPreferences.Editor` to edit preferences instead of using `prefs.edit().putInt("record", i);`. The docs say...

> Modifications to the preferences must go through an
>   SharedPreferences.Editor object to ensure the preference values remain
>   in a consistent state and control when they are committed to storage.

If you change your `setMethod` to the following it should work...

```
private void setRecord(int i ) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    if(i > prefs.getInt("record", 0))
        editor.putInt("record", i);

    editor.commit();
}
```

And I guess you are calling the above method `setRecord` somewhere in your code as I can't see it being called anywhere in the code snippet you pasted.

Comment: No worries @DomeWTF. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("record",i);
editor.commit();
```